# How to call a window function in isomorphic react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

In an Isomorphic react application we use same codebase for client and server.But how to call a window.function() from inside server(node js)call.

if I try to call some function in third party library it throws error as windows is undefined

Answer (score 2):

`window` is defined just when the component is mounted, so you cannot access any component which is binded to `window`.

Comment: Is there any way to use third party plugins in isomorphic react app?

Comment: Yes, but not the ones that nead the DOM to be loaded... or better, YOu can use any library, as soon as the DOM is initialized. So server side you can use libraries that are not loaded (using <script for example>) you have to import them. like in nodejs